# How to create an average chart based on another metric

Tags: looker-studio, data-studio-custom-visuals

I created a google data studio time series chart. The chart shows me the average availability for a large number of products on a weekly basis. I have another metric called turnover speed. I am trying to show the average availability per week only for the top 200 products on the basis of turn over speed. how can I do that?

Thanks

I tried creating a filter in data studio but the filter requires a certain value. The thing is, the top 200 products based on the turnover speed change per week. I would like the chart to calculate the average availability per week but only for the top 200 products in  terms of turnover speed in that given week.